# NFS mount command stuck without any error

Tags: nfs

NFS server: i added a path in /etc/exports

> > [local-path] [client-ip] (rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

run $exportfs -a
Succeeds!

NFS client:
Now run: $mount [server-ip]:[path] [local-path]

Now the mount command just gets stuck there, no error, no cli o/p.
How to even get what's the error?

Comment: Isn't this more a ServerFault.com question?

Comment: Did you try to ping to the mount point?

Answer (score 0):

This problem go sorted out by restarting the computer. I think nfs daemon restart should also work.